# pandas DataFrame update/combine when indices don't align

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider two dataframes which store information on the same characteristic of the same observation, but for different time periods:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"obs":["a","a","b","b"],
    "year":[1,2,1,2],
    "val":[3, np.NaN, 3, np.NaN]})

df1

Out:
   obs  val  year
0    a    3     1
1    a  NaN     2
2    b    3     1
3    b  NaN     2

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"obs":["a","a","b","b"],
    "val":[np.NaN, 4, np.NaN, 4],
    "year":[1,2,1,2]})
df2.index = (range(5,9))

df2

Out:
   obs  val  year
5    a  NaN     1
6    a    4     2
7    b  NaN     1
8    b    4     2
```

Now I would like to merge or combine these two data frames such that the values are collected in a single column, with the `NaN` in `df1` replaced by the corresponding observation-year values from `df2`.
I can achieve this by doing:

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["obs", "year"], how="left")
merged.loc[~np.isfinite(merged.val_x), 'val_x'] = merged[~np.isfinite(merged.val_x)].val_y
```

i.e. essentially doing a regular merge and then replacing the `NaN`s in one column with the values for the other column by hand.

Is there a better/more succinct way of doing this? I feel like some sort of `df.combine`, `df.combine_first`, `df.update` would do what I'm after, but they all seem to align on indices.

Comment: If the order is exactly the same couldn't you overwrite the index and then call `combine_first` so `df2.index = df1.index df1.combine_first(df2)`

Comment: I don't think this will work for my application, as the order is the same, but the data are unevenly spaced over time, so I could have year 1,2,4 in one dataset, and 2,3,4 in another. If I'm not mistaken re-indexing would then wrongly assign the years (as we're not checking the actual value of the year, just its position in the list)

Comment: Yes that's correct, I think your best bet is to merge like you have done already, to some extent as you are interested in just the values the index of the other df could be overwritten or reset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume your goal is to obtain `merged['val_x']` and that you really don't care about the other columns in `merged`.

Here are some options:

```
def using_merge(df1, df2):
    merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["obs", "year"], how="left")
    mask = ~np.isfinite(merged.val_x)
    merged.loc[mask, 'val_x'] = merged.loc[mask, 'val_y']
    return merged['val_x']

def using_update(df1, d2):
    merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["obs", "year"], how="left")
    merged['val_y'].update(merged['val_x'])
    return merged['val_y']

def using_set_index(df1, df2):
    df1 = df1.set_index(['obs','year'])
    df2 = df2.set_index(['obs','year'])
    return df1['val'].combine_first(df2['val'])
```

None is significantly more succinct than the others. But there is a bit of a performance difference:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools as IT

# generate a large-ish example
np.random.seed(2015)
N, M = 200, 200
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(IT.product(np.arange(N), np.arange(M))), 
                   columns=['obs','year'])
df1['val'] = np.random.choice([1,2,np.nan], size=len(df1))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(IT.product(np.arange(N), np.arange(M))), 
                   columns=['obs','year'])
df2['val'] = np.random.choice([1,2,np.nan], size=len(df1))
df2.index = np.arange(len(df2)) + len(df1)

m1 = using_merge(df1, df2)
m2 = using_update(df1, df2)
m3 = using_set_index(df1, df2)
assert m3.reset_index(drop=True).equals(m1)
assert m1.equals(m2)
```

---

```
In [158]: %timeit using_merge(df1, df2)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.6 ms per loop

In [159]: %timeit using_update(df1, df2)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.3 ms per loop

In [160]: %timeit using_set_index(df1, df2)
100 loops, best of 3: 8 ms per loop
```

So for larger DataFrames, it pays to set the index, and then use `combine_first`.

Comment: I'll accept this, as it seems that the sort of  super simple solution I was after doesn't actually exist. FWIW, I ended up writing a function very similar to the first one you proposed, as performance isn't critical for what I'm doing. Thanks!